# How do I resolve 500 error using vue @click with axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm having an issue with the axios (function?) with vue and Laravel. I have this running with a simple alert('something') - not using axios, just the alert in the function) but I'm getting these errors when running the current code

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/follow/2 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:86
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
followUser @ FollowButton.vue?618e:17
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:1859
invoker @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:2184
original._wrapper @ vue.common.dev.js?4650:7543
```

My code

```
methods: {
            followUser() {
                axios.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
                .then(response => {
                    alert(response.data);
                });
            }
        }
```

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE at 3:28:10 and I can't see where I've gone wrong for the life of me. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What's the server-side 500 error stack trace look like?

Comment: And 5XX error is from the server, and not from the vuejs .... try to inspect it from google developer tools (network tab and check xhr, you should see an red request). If you're not seeing the error, search for how to display all errors from laravel

Comment: @Joundill Sorry I'm not sure how I'd show that? Where would I find that?

Comment: @DMinch If you started the Laravel server with `php artisan serve`, then the error will likely be shown in the same console where you ran that `serve` command.

Comment: So it was as simple as needing to include my User controller in this one, grr. @SamuelAialaFerreira your advice put me on the right track, thanks. And thanks for the responses all.

Comment: @DMinch glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to include my User class - annoying